# How to set factory.setAckDiscarded(true) through application properties in spring kafka?

Tags: spring-kafka

How to set factory.setAckDiscarded(true) through application properties in spring kafka?

factory.setBatchListener(true);
factory.setAckDiscarded(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently settable via properties; you can add the factory as a parameter to any other `@Bean` definition and set it there.